# Swift: Frosted glass effect that can be applied to buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiblureffect

I am yet to find a suitable frosted glass effect/blur effect that works for buttons.

I am trying to blur anything behind the button but using UIVisualEffect blurEffect makes the button unusable. Also the range of .Light .ExtraLight and . Dark is not very extensive and doesn't give much edibility.

Any help would be great

Comment: How are you implementing the blurView? I have a custom UITabBarController with the tabBar blurred and it works exactly as expected.

Comment: the only way there is to implement it,<br/>var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)) as UIVisualEffectView<br/> It's just not the kind of effect I want, I just want to be able to edit it further than the 3 pre sets

Comment: are you adding it as a subview of your button view?

Comment: Yes I am adding it as a subview

Comment: You need to have the userInteraction set to false I believe - blur.userInteractionEnabled = false

Answer (score 1):

You could try this library:
https://github.com/unicorn/FlourishUI
It's not exactly what you are looking for, but you can use this for the blur effect, and even maybe keep the button. (See the demo on the github page).
I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion although if you scroll down and read the implementation you will notice this uses iOS's UIBlurEffects, the very ones I am trying to avoid. But thank you for taking the time to post an answer.